Make Proxmox CT act like it is on another network (site-to-site-vpn)
I currently host my Proxmox server at house #1 which is ideal due to the 2gigabit up/down internet. I have configured the TP-Link router at this house as an OpenVPN server and the TP-Link router at house #2 as an OpenVPN client. My question is this, is it possible to set up a container on my proxmox server that runs home assistant well for house #2 and Idealy prevent it from picking up devices at house #1. I want to mimick having a server hosted on house #2 network without moving my proxmox server there (it has 20mbps upload speeds)
